# How to detect gesture over ImageView?

Tags: android, android-input-method

I'd like to detect finger being dragged over ImageView. I get my ImageView, create instances of GestureDetector and View.OnTouchListener, then set View.OnTouchListener to ImageView.

OnTouchListener detects all touches ("touch occured") and I pass them to GestureDetector, but it never calls its methods onScroll or onFling. What I am doing wrong? Bellow you can see related source:

```
    myImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    myGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this,
            new GestureDetector.OnGestureListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public void onShowPress(MotionEvent e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2,
                        float distanceX, float distanceY) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Log.d("gestures", "scroll");
                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2,
                        float velocityX, float velocityY) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Log.d("gestures", "fling");
                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    return false;
                }

            });



    gestureListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (myGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)) {
                Log.d("gestures", "here");
                return true;
            }

            Log.d("gestures", "touch occured");
            return false;
        }
    };

    myImageView.setOnTouchListener(gestureListener);
```

Comment: can you tell me what you have to do ?

Comment: have you implemented OnGestureListener?

Comment: I want to detect drag motion over ImageView and move scaled image in a ImageView. Also why do I have to implement it if I only want to assign it to one ImageView, not whole Activity Layout.

Comment: Sorry, guys ATM have lots of work and cant get to programming. Will get to these answers in few days.

Comment: At the end I didnt succeed in making myGestureDetector working and I ended up writting my own onTouch() method for View.OnTouchListener() which detects draging by comparing MotionEvent.getX / getY values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will also need to override the onTouchEvent method. I have detected onFling() gesture on imageview like this.

```
   @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
                return myGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
```

The code which is working at my end is:

```
 public class AddNewTask extends Activity implements OnClickListener,OnTouchListener ,GestureDetector.OnGestureListener
    {
  private GestureDetector gestures;
    private ImageView imgViewPreview;
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.addtask);

     gestures = new GestureDetector(AddNewTask.this,
                         this);
    imgViewPreview.setOnTouchListener(this);

    }

    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
     {
        if(v==imgViewPreview)
          if(gestures.onTouchEvent(event))
             return true;


        return false;
    }

    @Override
     public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) 
    {
       return gestures.onTouchEvent(event);      

     }

}
```

Comment: if I add this, I get compile error. I only get pass withouth @Override notation, but nothing happens. To my understanding method onTouchEvent() should determine the type of the gesture and call certain method, like  onFling(). Do you have actual code, that works?

Comment: Yes you are right.May I know what is the error which you are getting at compile time?

Comment: I have added working code above please check whether this works at your end. :)

Comment: I do not know the exact reason, but when I added longclick listener to imageview it was working fine. But was not working when I removed it. Please try to add longclick listner to the imageview.

Answer (score 2):

**onDown** method of OnGestureListener must always return **true** otherwise the detector won't react to the following events as a result onScroll won't be invoked.

Comment: Thank you. Its seems now it reacts. I'll try to implement some filtering for gesture sizing and if this change is the only needed thing to make this work, I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a customised gesture listener class by extending [SimpleOnGestureListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener.html). Also by doing so, you will be able to  override all the above methods as well.

Comment: I have tried SimpleOnGestureListener but again these methods were not called back.

Answer (score 0):

First resolve the error which you are facing when you have used @Override.

This is mostly because of the lower Java compiler Configurations[application properties->Java Compiler->Compiler compliance level] Make sure it is 1.6.

Once this is solved, try again with @Override notations.